# A property of Sobolev spaces on bounded domains

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to show the following:

$\forall u \in H_0^s(\Omega), u \ne 0, \exists \psi \in H_0^s(\Omega)$ s.t. $h'(0) \ne 0$, in which $h(t)=\int_{\Omega} |u+t\psi|^{p+1}$. Here $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded domain, and $H_0^s(\Omega)$ is the Sobolev space on this domain.

It is not difficult to show that $h'(0)=(p+1) \int_\Omega u^p \psi$, yet I don't know how to proceed. (probably this "not difficult" statement is incorrect) Any solutions or hints will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you not simply choose $\psi = u$?

Comment: @gerw Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have tried $\psi = u$, but I am not sure whether $u \ne 0$ can lead to $\int_\Omega u^{p+1} \ne 0$. A possible approach might be $ u \ne 0 \Rightarrow ||u||_{H_0^s} \ne 0 \Rightarrow \int_\Omega u^{p+1} \ne 0$, yet I cannot figure out the last "$\Rightarrow$".

Comment: I think your expression for $h'(0)$ is wrong. In case $\psi = u$, we directly have $h(t) = (1+t)^{p+1} \int_\Omega |u|^{p+1}$.

Comment: @gerw You are right. I have already edited my expression.

Comment: This is still not right. I think you have to replace $u^p$ by $|u|^{p-1} u$.